# TYPO3 V9: Howto omit special characters in URL?

Tags: routes, typo3, special-characters, typo3-9.x

The routes for tx_news are configured and working fine. Now I have a category called "Local Development" which results in an URL like:

[https://example.com/category/Local Development]

How can the space be ommited?

Also Umlaut and other special characters are transfered as they are to the URL:

[[https://example.com/category/Bürgerbegehren]](https://example.com/category/B%C3%BCrgerbegehren])

Is it a bug? Or can it be omited by configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without you providing your configuration and currently used version of tx_news, I can only make assumptions.

You maybe simply configured your "routFieldName" for your "category-name" to select from "title" field.

Since tx_news 7.1 there is a added field called "slug" in "sys_category" which contains the "url-friendly" varian of your category-title.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! ;-)